# Use fragment to load a layout file which contains a ListView ,initialize the ListView adapter in this fragment class.But see noting

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I use `NewsTitleFragment` class to load the layout file `news_title_frag.xml`. This file only contains a `ListView`. Using the `findViewById` to get the `ListView` instance,and set the adapter. But can't see anything

This is my `NewsTitleFragment.class`:

```
public class NewsTitleFragment extends Fragment{

    private ListView newsTitleListView;

    private List<News> newsList;

    private NewsAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        newsList = getNews();
        adapter = new NewsAdapter(context,R.layout.news_item,newsList);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_title_frag,container,false);
        newsTitleListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_title_list_view);
        newsTitleListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

    private List<News> getNews(){
        List<News> newsList = new ArrayList<News>();
        News news1 = new News();
        news1.setContent("At this point in the campaign, even with the first votes fewer than 50 days away, national polls are not always the reliable predictors of where presidential nominating contests are heading. At this time four years ago, former congressman Newt Gingrich was tied with eventual nominee Mitt Romney on the Republican side. Eight years ago, former New York City mayor Rudy Giuliani led the GOP field, while Hillary Clinton held a wide lead over then-Sen. Barack Obama among Democrats. Giuliani and Clinton eventually lost.");
        news1.setTitle("In face of criticism, Trump surges to his biggest lead over the GOP field");
        newsList.add(news1);

        News news2 = new News();
        news2.setContent("“This is an emerging humanitarian crisis. There is extreme suffering, and people are not being protected,” said Rae McGrath, country director for Turkey and North Syria for the American aid agency Mercy Corps, one of the largest providers of food aid in northern Syria. Since the Russian strikes began, the agency has been able to deliver only a fifth of the amount it normally provides, he said.");
        news2.setTitle("Russian airstrikes force a halt to aid in Syria, triggering a new crisis");
        newsList.add(news2);

        News news3 = new News();
        news3.setTitle("For many at Liberty University, guns and God go hand in hand");
        news3.setContent("Many students, faculty members and administrators said they agreed with his views. Hundreds said they planned to take free classes from Liberty police on gun safety, a step toward obtaining a state permit to carry a concealed weapon. Among them were 21-year-old students Alvonta Tarrant and Dominique Richbur");
        newsList.add(news3);

        return newsList;
    }
}
```

This is my `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.example.gaby.fragmentbestpractice.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/news_title_fragment"
            android:name="com.example.gaby.fragmentbestpractice.NewsTitleFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is my `news_title_frag`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/news_title_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my `new_item.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/news_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

This is the `News.class`:

```
public class News {

    private String title;

    private String content;

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

This is my adapter class `NewsAdapter.class`:

```
package com.example.gaby.fragmentbestpractice;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by Gaby on 12/14/2015.
 */
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<News>{

    private int resourceId;

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<News> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        resourceId = textViewResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        News news = getItem(position);
        View view;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView == null){
            view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(resourceId,null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else{
            view = convertView;
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.textView.setText(news.getTitle());
        return view;
    }
```

The running result is like is:

[image]

There should be several titles,what's wrong?

Comment: Please, post the XML layout of the fragment with the ListView. Your code looks fine until now

Comment: Change this  `view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(resourceId,parent ,false);`

Comment: that doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change below lines to onCreateView method instead of onAttach . it will work :)

```
 newsList = getNews();
        adapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.new_item,newsList);
```

Comment: onAttach(Context) is not called on pre API 23 versions of Android @郭佳乐

Comment: @anoopg87 thats it - I suppose. Other solution is to use: ` public void onAttach(Activity activity)`.

Comment: @anoopg87 thaks, buddy!

Answer (score 2):

Code you have shown us looks correct, so the problem is somewhere else, ie. with your main activity layout, it should load your fragment, it should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.gaby.fragmentbestpractice.NewsTitleFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

also make sure your fragment xml file is also correct, it should look something like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/news_title_list_view"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I change my two file into yours,but there is still nothing

Comment: @郭佳乐 I have no idea whats wrong, I have created a test project with your code and it shows OK on sgs4 - see here: https://github.com/luskan/TestApp

Comment: I put my code on github see here:[https://github.com/gabygoole/TestApp](https://github.com/gabygoole/TestApp). Can you please clone to local,and run it, I wonder if the machine difference cause that problem.

Comment: I have figured out,It seems not the problem of code-
Correctness. Remove the code:                                                           `newsList = getNews();
        adapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.new_item,newsList);` to onCreateView will show the content. Your TestApp just write all the class in  `MainActivity`,So you didn't met the problem.  I am still wondering why this

Comment: @郭佳乐 sorry I was not able to compile your project

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this function in your adapter class if you havent(as i cant see in here)

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return objects.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should extend BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter, In your code you used ArrayAdapter, your new_item.xml should contains only TextView like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/news_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        />
```